# How to link to site's default language from alternate language using l() function in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm building a multi-lingual website using drupal 7.

Now, I'm in the process of adding a link manually that links back to site's default language from the alternate language.

E.g. from "mysite.com/fr" I want to build a link that links to "mysite.com/"

How can do that using the l() function ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, figured it out.

I had to use `language` inside the $options array inside the `l()` function.